# Why does my webpage refresh when I execute the "save" function in Django?

Tags: html, django, vue.js

Why does my webpage refresh when I execute the "save" function in Django?

This is my Django, HTML, and Vue code. I can't figure out the reason, but I know that the webpage refreshes after executing the save() function. I don't want the page to reset, as it would also cause a refresh for other users accessing the webpage simultaneously.
The data is being successfully uploaded, but is there any specific reason causing the webpage to refresh?

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.FILES.get('file')
        if file:
            filename = file.name
            post = ModelWithFileField()
            post.upload = file
            post.OnlyForDatabase = file
            post.filename = filename
            post.upload_date = date.today()
            post.save()  
        return Response(post.id, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Performance Tuning Database</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return false">
      <input type="file" ref="fileInput" />
      <button type="submit" @click="upload">Upload</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="JS/welcome copy.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    APIip: sessionStorage.getItem('API_IP'),
    token: sessionStorage.getItem('token'),
  },
  methods: {
    async upload(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); 
      const fileInput = this.$refs.fileInput;
      const file = fileInput.files[0];
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      console.log(formData)
      this.message = formData
      const response = await axios.post(this.APIip + "/api/file/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          'Authorization': 'token ' + this.token
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: I think somehow even though you are using `preventDefault` the submit event is still being triggered on the form, an easy way to check if this is the case is to remove the `type="submit"` from the button and see if it works, since you have your own logic for submitting the attribute is not necessary as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Visual Studio to open the port, and I found that separating the upload path and the web page path prevents the webpage from refreshing. Although I'm not sure why this happens, I have successfully resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage refreshes after executing the "save()" function in Django because the form submission is triggering a default behavior of refreshing the page. To prevent this, you can modify your Vue code by removing the "onsubmit" attribute from the form tag and handling the form submission using the Vue method.

Here's the updated code:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" ref="fileInput" />
  <button type="button" @click="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

In your Vue method, remove the line `event.preventDefault();` as it is not needed anymore.

```
async upload() {
  //event.preventDefault(); 
}
```

Comment: I tried it once, but it still refreshed the page.
Can't find out why this is happening.

Comment: Do you put type=“button” in the button element, because default type of button is “submit” and it will trigger the form submission

Comment: Yes, I followed your way of writing type = "button", the same webpage refresh.